# using merge in R to fill in the NA in a data.frame

Tags: r, merge

I have a dataframe `a` that a few cells' information is missing, I have gathered the missing data and created another dataframe `b` afterwards.

Usually I fill in the missing data by the following code:

```
for (loop.b in (1:nrow(b)))
    {a[a[,"uid"]==b[loop.b,"uid"],"var1"] <- b[loop.b,"var1"]
    }
```

This works OK for me, but what if `b` is having lots of rows? Then the explicit loop will make the process slow. Is there any more elegant way for doing this kind of "missing data replacement" work?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at `norm` package and `prelim.norm` function. `Hmisc` has good imputation facility, not to mention `mi`... CRAN package list is a good place to start.

Comment: Oh, and, btw, get rid of that nasty loop... =)

Comment: I may be dense, could you help me out by posting a small reproducible example?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the two following data frames are similar to what you describe :

```
R> a <- data.frame(uid=1:10,var1=c(1:3,NA,5:7,NA,9:10))
R> a
   uid var1
1    1    1
2    2    2
3    3    3
4    4   NA
5    5    5
6    6    6
7    7    7
8    8   NA
9    9    9
10  10   10

R> b <- data.frame(uid=c(8,4),var1=c(74,82))
R> b
  uid var1
1   8   74
2   4   82
```

Then you may use directly the following :

```
R> a[b$uid,"var1"] <- b$var1
```

Which gives :

```
R> a
   uid var1
1    1    1
2    2    2
3    3    3
4    4   82
5    5    5
6    6    6
7    7    7
8    8   74
9    9    9
10  10   10
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
# matches of a$uid in b$uid, NA if not match
ind = match(a$uid, b$uid) 
# 'ind' are the index in b and NA, we remove the latter
a[!is.na(ind),"var1"] = b[ind[!is.na(ind)],"var1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `match`, but it's hard to guess at what your data are like.

```
## a's var1 has some missing values
a <- data.frame(var1 = c(1, NA, 4.5, NA, 6.5), uid = 5:1)
## b knows all about them
b <- data.frame(var1 = c(2.3, 8.9), uid = c(2, 4))

## find the indexes in a$uid that match b$uid
ind <- match(b$uid, a$uid)

## those indexes now can be filled directly with b$uid
a$var1[ind] <- b$var1
```

That will work even if the uids are not unique (though the name sort of suggests that they are).